# Can the Moller cross-section be calculated using a two-particle potential?

Tags: scattering-cross-section

Can the Moller scattering cross section be calculated with a two-particle potential?

The Feynman prescription for scattering two electrons, using perturbation theory (Weinberg QTF Vol1) involves squaring the J*A interaction Hamiltonian of particle "a" and ascribing the second factor to a different particle in a different field. Then tries to connect 2 independent interactions with Time-ordered propagators.. The dimensions are fudged so that JA has dimension sqrt(alpha).
Lotta armwaving going on...
All other physics uses two-particle potentials ... ???
My Question is Can the Moller scattering amplitude and differential cross-section be calculated using a two-particle potential?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hope the edit clarifies the question.